# How to bind the DAS keyboard volume knob in dwm / void linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, alsa, dwm, void-linux, audio-volume

My setup: Void Linux, xorg, dwm + dmenu + st, DAS keyboard.

I can probably figure out how to bind some "normal" keys for volume control, but I really like this big round knob on my keyboard :).

So, how to make the volume control to work from my keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

In my `config.h`, somewhere near or at the top, create pointers to array of strings representing the CLI commands to control volume on your system. The included  `X11/XF86keysym.h` contains key symbols for controls "found on some 'Internet' keyboards". I'm using ALSA, so for me the utility is `amixer`.

```
#include <X11/XF86keysym.h>

static const char *volumeup[] = {"amixer", "-c", "1", "-q", "set", "Master", "2%+", NULL};
static const char *volumedown[] = {"amixer", "-c", "1", "-q", "set", "Master",  "2%-", NULL};
static const char *toggle[] = {"amixer", "-c", "1", "-q", "set", "Master",  "toggle", NULL};
```

In the same file, add the pointers to the `keys[]` array, like:

```
static const Key keys[] = {


    /* modifier                     key        function        argument */
    { 0,        XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume,        spawn,        { .v = volumeup } },
    { 0,        XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume,        spawn,        { .v = volumedown }},
    { 0,               XF86XK_AudioMute,        spawn,        { .v = toggle }},
```

Then the usual

```
make
sudo make install
make clean
```

One must figure out the channel (the `-c` option). For this, `/proc/asound/modules` will be helpful. On Void, one might need to explicitly configure ALSA, see the docs at https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/media/alsa.html

Answer (score -1):

Try `xev`, it explain keycodes. As you haven't described what the problem is, I assume you don't know keycode.

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the problem (which is stated in my question). `xev` does not react to my keyboard's volume control in any way.